# Shell script that validates file in hdfs

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs, oozie, oozie-workflow

I'm trying to make a script to check if there is any file missing in a hdfs path. The idea is to include it in an oozie workflow that when no file is found fails and does not continue with the flow

```
ALTRAFI="/input/ALTrafi*.txt"
ALTDATOS="/ALTDatos*.txt"
ALTARVA="/ALTarva*.txt"
TRAFCIER="/TrafCier*.txt"

if hdfs dfs -test -e $ALTRAFI; then
   echo "[$ALTRAFI] Archive not found"
   exit 1
fi
if hdfs dfs -test -e $ALTDATOS; then
   echo "[$ALTDATOS] Archive not found"
   exit 2
fi
if hdfs dfs -test -e $ALTARVA; then
   echo "[$ALTARVA] Archive not found"
   exit 3
fi   
if hdfs dfs -test -e $TRAFCIER; then
   echo "[$TRAFCIER] Archive not found"
   exit 4
fi
```

But the script does not fail when it does not find a file and continues the flow of the workflow in oozie

oozie flow:

```
<start to="ValidateFiles"/>
<kill name="Kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<action name="ValidateFiles">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
              <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
              <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>tez.lib.uris</name>
                <value>/hdp/apps/2.5.0.0-1245/tez/tez.tar.gz</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <exec>/produccion/apps/traficotasado/ValidateFiles.sh</exec>
        <file>/produccion/apps/traficotasado/ValidateFiles.sh#ValidateFiles.sh</file> <!--Copy the executable to compute node's current working directory -->
    </shell>
    <ok to="CopyFiles"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>
</action>   
  <action name="CopyFiles">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
              <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
              <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>tez.lib.uris</name>
                <value>/hdp/apps/2.5.0.0-1245/tez/tez.tar.gz</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <exec>/produccion/apps/traficotasado/CopyFiles.sh</exec>
        <file>/produccion/apps/traficotasado/CopyFiles.sh#CopyFiles.sh</file> <!--Copy the executable to compute node's current working directory -->
    </shell>
    <ok to="DepuraFilesStage"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>
</action>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't know this tool, but aren't these conditions all inverted? Surely you'd want to check `if ! hdfs dfs -test ...`

Comment: Have you verified that it's supposed to work with globs?

Comment: Works with: if ! hdfs dfs..... Thank you. Now I have problems with the flow of oozie, when I can not find the file, I should not continue but he continues with the next task

Comment: I've added a `[hadoop]` tag, note the low number of followers for ozzie-workflow. Good luck.

Comment: **1.** from general principles, when using a glob'ed expression with an HDFS command line, enclose it with quotes otherwise the shell will try to match it with local files ; e.g. `-test -e "$ALTRAFI"`

Comment: **2.** your shell logs messages to StdOut : did you check the YARN logs to see what messages have been logged there?

Comment: If you have the possibility to put archives in different HDFS directories for instance /inpout/ALTDatos, just check that the input directories are not empty with several Oozie decisions
`<decision name="check ALTDatos ">
    <switch>
      <case to="nextStep">${fs:dirSize(alttadosDir) gt 0}</case>
      <default to="end" />
    </switch>
  </decision>
`

Comment: I managed to work with a "set -e" at the beginning of the shell, Thank you very much for all your suggestions. Interesting Harold's option, I'll take it into account